# How can I undo a horcrux when I'm unable to go through a process of deep remorse for the murder committed to create the Horcrux?

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

I was trying to surf the net with Google Chromium today, and the first site I visited was stackoverflow.com. Since I visited as a visitor, I was searching the user of myself, and surprisingly found a [Horcrux of me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927012/ken-kin).

I've once doubted that it was just another person has the same name with me. But from the **terrible coding style**, **personal profile** and the **poor English**, I believe that he **is** me, although I can't recall what happened.

[Horcruxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horcrux#Horcruxes) made from inanimate objects are extremely difficult to destroy .. a Horcrux must suffer damage so severe that repair through magical means .. and I tried the magic told by this answer:

- [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist/18233#18233).

I tried to contact, and it said `Thank you for contacting the Stack Exchange Team. You should receive an email response shortly.`. After a couple of hours, however, I still have not received even a single email, and I've just given it the second try.

I do not have sufficient evidence to prove that the Horcrux is of me, and I'm worried about that my request will not be processed.

What should I do further?

Comment: Beautiful. Simply beautiful.

Comment: "a couple of hours" is not enough time. Give it a couple of days at least.

Comment: You did try a killing curse? If so, try basilisk venom as an alternative. But yeah, what @Dukeling. Keep in mind that the US side of SE is only getting started. And even if you don't get a response today, give it some time.

Comment: Wait for Shog9 to show up. He's a basilisk. That's why he wears shades.

Comment: @yhw that explains so, so much I've been puzzling about the past couple of years.

Comment: Developer can "ping" the email associated with that other account, then if you can reply to it that's all the proof they need. If not... well, let the poor thing live. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I'm afraid I cannot ..

Comment: Well, there are over 1000 (!!!) users with the exact same name "Dan" or "dan" - so you're not alone.

Comment: @FEichinger: Beautiful .. what? I do not get you ..

Comment: @KenKin I'm sure FEichinger meant the way you asked this question, not the problem you're facing. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Very much, yes.

Comment: Oh .. surprisingly ..

Comment: Absolutely nothing is going to get me to click on "Recursive CreateDirectory" with that sort of build-up.

Comment: Have your best friend kill the snake.

Comment: @Dukeling I'd give it 6 to 8 weeks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This request has now been processed and resolved, but I'm putting up an answer for posterity anyway.)

> What should I do further?

**Wait for a response.** The requests from the contact form go into our support system where they're processed by humans and these things take time.

We have various processes we follow to confirm ownership of accounts for merging. The main one being that we ask people to edit both profiles to include something like "merge me" in the "About Me" sections.

That obviously doesn't work when someone doesn't have access to one of the profiles anymore. We have a few options from there - we can match the information on both profiles, we can ask the user to provide some information to us that isn't available publicly on the profile, etc.

If I recall your specific case, the two accounts were pretty obviously similar, so we processed the merge.

Comment: -1 for not suggesting to read _Harry Potter_ while waiting for response

Comment: Thank you and SE team. There is another user [Ken King](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1738759/ken-king) and I'm seriously doubt it was also me when I changing my login method from Google to StackExchange. King is the family name my father uses, but as King is just a transliteration of our family name in Mandarin and I don't want to inherit a name looks arrogant, I changed mine. May I ask SE team to confirm that user also?

Comment: @KenKin That's profile belongs to somebody else.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @KenKin Just FYI, “King” is a common Western surname and wouldn't be noticed as unusual. Generally, names common in English are not thought of as words, even when they match a word. (For perspective, King is the 37th most common surname in the U.S. [according to the 2000 census](http://www.census.gov/topics/population/genealogy/data/2000_surnames.html).)